# What does sharp (#) (e.g. #{$variable}) mean in SCSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I was checking out an article and came across something like the following:

```
$desktop-width: 1024px;

@mixin desktop {
  @media(min-width: #{$desktop-width}) {
    ...
  }
}
```

And was wondering why the use of sharp (#)? Can't you just do `min-width: $desktop-width`?

Thank you in advance and will accept answer/up vote

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`#{}` is responsible for a string interpolation so in the example above it is not needed and can be omitted.

Comment: When would you use string interpolation over regular $ variables? I don't really see any real use of it.

Comment: For example you could use it for margin-top:, margin-left:, margin-right: etc. as margin-#{direction}:

Comment: This way you can create a mixin that will take direction as an argument and apply it to margin-.

Answer (score 1):

`#{}` is used for string interpolation: http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_

> There is one exception to this, though: when using #{} interpolation, quoted strings are unquoted. This makes it easier to use e.g. selector names in mixins. For example.

So this technique is used sometimes to allow using sass values in selectors. E.g.:

```
$gutter: 10;

.grid#{$gutter} {
    background: red;
}
```

Now to your question. I really don't see any reason why would anybody use string interpolation in this selector:

```
#{h1, h2, h3, h4, h5}
{
    color: #000;
}
```

My best guess is that sass variable will be added later to that selector, or the selector will be completely replaced with a variable.

Comment: What would `.grid#{$gutter}` do? It is `.grid10` right? When would you use string interpolation over regular `$` variables? I don't really see any real use of it.

Answer (score 0):

It, combined with `{}` indicates something that should be [interpolated](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_).

i.e. replaced with the value of a variable.

Comment: When would you use string interpolation over regular $ variables? I don't really see any real use of it.

Comment: @JoKo — Because you want to use it somewhere a variable isn't allowed (such as in the middle of another string, or in a selector)